# Remove snapshot function from app windows when pressing ALT+space?

Tags: 22.04, shortcut-keys

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, and discovered a tremendously annoying feature. Whenever I wish to hide/minimize an app window, I have pressed `ALT` + `SPACE` on my keyboard, and then `SPACE` again. This hides the window on 20.04, and it is fast and effortless, comes without thinking.
On 22.04, however, when pressing `ALT` + `SPACE` the first option is "Take snapshot", so pressing `space` will only result in that. I now have a Snapshot folder with tons of useless snapshots...

Is there some way to disable this annoying feature and get back the old functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, without changing source code yourself. You may want to change your habits and hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to hide a window, which is even a bit quicker.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry to hear that though. Yes, Super + H is fewer keys to press - but requires more precision. ;-)